# How can I test an iOS App I am creating and simulate a Chinese user?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

I am developing an app that will be used world-wide and have a co-worker who lives in China. He claims it takes a very long time to reach our server here in the US and I want to be able to use the app on my phone but through a VPN and proxy on my iPhone so it appears that I am in China. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-cn/) you can find a list of Chinese web proxies.

You should also change your app so that it goes to through the proxy. This depends on how you are dealing with HTTP communication but if you google it, you will find many posts.

Keep in mind that a proxy will add a further delay in communication.

If you want to setup a VPN, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-on-your-mac-and-access-everything-remotely-with-an-iphone/) for setting up a VPN on your Mac and then connect the iPhone to it.

Comment: What about the VPN? Im not the Objective C coder and dont have the source code. I just have the compiled app on my phone. I need to be able to test the app as if I were in China. This proxy solution would work if I could modify the source but I think I am going to need to be going through a VPN. Also keep in mind I am not talking about using a proxy through Safari. My iPhone has to be setup to use a VPN for iOS apps unless I am mistaken.

Comment: that's true, if you have not the code available, you need to use a VPN. I added a link to a tutorial.